# Unix line endings under Windows

Tags: unix, tcl, eol

I need to generate a file with Unix line endings (\n) in my Windows environment. The following script still generates the default Windows line endings, despite the `fconfigure` command. How can I fix this?

```
set fid [open "myfile.txt" "WRONLY CREAT TRUNC"]
fconfigure $fid -eofchar \n
puts $fid "hello"
close $fid
```

Comment: Which editor are you using. Is this in Shell? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `-translation lf` on that channel. (`binary` would also work, but that shorthand also changes other features of the channel, such as the encoding and EOF marker.)

```
fconfigure $fid -translation lf
```

Don't set `-eofchar` to newline; that's very unlikely to be what you want! (It's also not nearly so important on output; we don't automatically write the EOF marker when you close the file.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Got a little bit messed up by EOF and EOL...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a clarification: `-eofchar` is for end-of-file, verus OPs need to set end-of-line character.